# How to display the rectangles on the canvas which are stored in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, canvas

```
Rectangle arr[]=new Rectangle[20];
    void input()
    {
    x=10;y=20;
    for(int i=1;i<20;i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,40,10);
        arr[i]=r;
    }
}
```

I used an array arr to store 20 rectangle objects
Now I wish to display them on the canvas.How could I do that using the  elements in the array.I am confused because i am not able to use Graphics2d object.Can anyone show me the contents of the paint method for drawing the rectangles.Also how can I make these rectangles disappear?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the standard `Graphics` class?

Comment: I didn't follow but there are no restrictions.I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You said you are not able to use `Graphics2D`; does this mean you don't know how to use it? I thought it meant you weren't allowed.  Have you looked into examples online? This is a very basic question, and I fear it might get closed due to lack of research effort. I'll help, but you need to ask a *specific* question. Why are you not able to use it?

Comment: yeah.i know how to use graphic2d,graphic which casting too but my problem is that when i use array for storing the rectangle objects,i cannot connect them with the paint method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be you using a map instead of an array, that way you can access each rectangle. Try this code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
```

include these imports

```
Map<Integer, Rectangle> RectangleMap;

void(input)
{
    RectangleMap = new HashMap<Integer, Rectangle>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        RectangleMap.put(i, new Rectangle(x,y,40,10))
    }
}
```

Now you have a map with twenty rectangles labeled 0-19, to access a rectangle, for example rectangle 3, use

```
RectangleMap.get(3);
```

Now you could do something like

```
RectangleMap.get(3).setColor(Color.BLUE);
RectangleMap.get(3).fill();
```

note, you will need appropriate graphics imports